# How to use step wizard ui component in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I want to add the step-wizard form in my UI form, but I am unable to find the xml configuration needed to create the step-wizard in Magento 2.

Note: I already have tried the Modifier way as in Product Form but was not successful.

The example are given below.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/pattern-library/navigation/wizard/wizard.html

[image]

Comment: Have you found any solution for it?

Comment: Not yet. There is some basic structure in `module-UI`, I think I need to research and add the proper definition in dev docs as It's quite needed.

Comment: Have you got any solution ?

Comment: Also looking for this.

Comment: Looking for this

Comment: @MilindSingh, did you found anything ? I need to apply same.